# In Cassandra database the Table created in CQL is not seen in CLI?

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface, cql

In Cassandra database the Table created in CQL is not seen in CLI in same column family is there any reference reason for the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because two diffrent protocols are used to create the column family. You are creating the 'table' using the CQL binary protocol and then you are trying to edit it using the THRIFT interface (through CLI), this is not allowed on purpose. From the Cassandra CTO:

> This is by design. CLI and Thrift-based consumers in general do not know how to understand CQL3 metadata, and would do the Wrong Thing without realizing it.

You can find the documented "issue" [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5246).

If you wanted to access the data in the table you created you can use [cqlsh](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/dml/using_cql#using-cql).